# Making spaces after inserting figures as pdf in latex?

Tags: pdftex, pdf, pdfpages, subfig

Making spaces after inserting figures as pdf in latex. After adding png or jpg, there is no space between the text under the figure. However, when I upload it as a pdf, it leaves a space between it and the text. How can I remove this space?

I save the graphics I created in matlab as pdf. When I put these graphic pdfs in latex it leaves spaces. I show an example of this in the picture. I hope I was able to explain.

[image]

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \scalebox{0.5}{\includegraphics{blockdiagram.pdf}}
    \caption{Block diagram of the signal processing part for detection analysis.}   
    \label{block_dia}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is a bit hard to understand what you mean. Could you provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/47927) or at least a picture of what you have and/or what you want to achieve?

Comment: Please provide a MWE (minimal working example) following the demands you find here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/231952, so that we can better understand the problem you are encountering.

Comment: the space below the caption could be due to many things, as you have shown no code it is hard to guess, but it will not be due to using pdf or png as the image format.

Comment: your code fragment is not of any help. Inserting it in standard `article` document with some example image doesn't reproduce your problem. Please provide complete document, which we can compile as it is and which reproduce your problem. For text and image use `lipsum` (or similar) package, for image example image with about the same size. BTW, better than use of `[H]` for figure placement is to use `[ht]` or `[htbp]˙.

Comment: I also see no reason to use `\scalebox` here `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{...}` seems a lot easier

Comment: Maybe the PDF you inserted is a tiny bit larger than the PNG. Therefore, TeX will adjust the surrounding paragraphs differently. Depending on what precedes and follows the figure, this may be due to TeX trying to avoid other bad things such as widows or orphans etc. We need a bit more code than just the code for the `figure` environment to tell more.

Comment: I don't know what else to share. After the \end{figure} statement, I immediately start typing. I am sharing your example.     \begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \scalebox{0.5}{\includegraphics{blockdiagram.pdf}}
  \caption{Block diagram of the signal processing part for detection analysis.} 
  \label{block_dia}
 \end{figure} 
 For the offset estimation, the mean of the first $B$ sample of each signal is assumed as the offset of the signal.